# Loading a picture via $http causes an infinite $digest

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to load an image in a `div` with a function in a *ng-style* and it is causing an infinite $digest loop along the lines of this.

```
<div ng-style="userPicture(user.id)">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</div>
```

```
$scope.userPicture = function(userId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var url = '/api/picture/' + userId;
    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.result && response.data.result.picture){
            var picture = response.data.result.picture.replace("?t=small", "");
            deferred.resolve({
                'background-image': "url('" + picture + "')",
                'color': 'transparent'
            });
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The error displayed in the console

> ```
> Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
> Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
> ```

I read the explanation of the error in the link, and it sounds like this is caused by the function making AngularJS think that the value has changed infinitely which triggers a digest.

How do I go about creating a function that accepts a parameter and returns the style in this manner?

Comment: The `ng-style` directive does not unwrap promises. That was removed from the AngularJS framework many years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-style` directive does not unwrap promises. That was removed from the AngularJS framework many years ago.

Instead of having the HTML retreive the data from the server, do it in the controller:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div ng-style="userPicStyleHash[user.id]">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$scope.userPicStyleHash = {};

$scope.users.forEach(user => getStyle($scope.userPicStyleHash,user.id));

function getStyle(obj,userId) {
    var url = '/api/picture/' + userId;
    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var result = response.data.result;
        if (result && result.picture){
            var picture = result.picture.replace("?t=small", "");
            var style = {
                'background-image': "url('" + picture + "')",
                'color': 'transparent'
            };
            obj[userId] = style;
        }
    });
}
```